# Force IntelliJ to link to Maven dependency documentation when generating Javadoc?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javadoc

I am using Stanford's CoreNLP package in my project in IntelliJ as a Maven dependency. When I generate Javadoc for my project (Tools > Generate Javadoc) it does not link to the documentation for CoreNLP. For instance, if one of my methods takes in a parameter of type [Sentence](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/simple/Sentence.html) (from the edu.stanford.nlp.simple package), then the method signature in the generated Javadoc will have edu.stanford.nlp.simple.Sentence as the type of the parameter with no hyperlink. Is there any way to include Maven dependency documentation such that the generated Javadoc will have the type of the parameter be just Sentence which is hyperlinked to the documentation for that CoreNLP class?

In the "Generate Javadoc" dialog box, I have both "Include JDK and library sources in -sourcepath" and "Include link to JDK documentation" selected.

Comment: It would help to include the code with the Javadoc from your project

Comment: Try using maven to do this rather than intellij